# ANT throwing exception

Tags: java, ant, classpath

My enviromental variables are  set like this

ANT_HOME=c:\ant1.6
JAVA_HOME=c:jdk.16

And path includes both %JAVA_HOME%/bin and %ANT_HOME%/bin

Still when I execute ant -version from command prompt it thows an exception like below don't know why its doing that

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/AntMain
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:244)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.AntMain

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 17 more
```

Comment: In a command prompt, please run the following commands: `where ant`, `java -version`, `findstr /B /C:"<title>" %ANT_HOME%\docs\manual\cover.html`. Edit your question, and add the output from those commands. This will let us know what versions of Ant and Java we're dealing with.

Comment: Try downloading latest version of Ant and set the ANT_HOME variable and then try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [`ant-launcher.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant-launcher/1.10.5) is missing from the classpath, which is a separate dependency from main [`ant.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant/1.10.5).